# Echo Results of a Variable in Sed Replacement

Tags: linux, bash, text-processing, sed, cygwin

I have a file called `LoginExcInternal.txt` which has data that looks like the following:

```
Name1   OpenFin/111.111.111.111
Name2   OpenFin/111.111.111.112
Name3   Chrome/111.111.111.111
```

These two columns are being separated by `tabs`.

I need to output this to another file which will replace both `OpenFin` and `Chrome` with `=VLOOKUP('Mar 19'!A4,'User-Firm'!A2:B1999,2,FALSE)`

The `Mar 19` should always show the month and year for last Monday.

This is what I have so far:

```
z="$(date -d 'last Sunday - 6 day' '+%b %y')" && sed 's/OpenFin.*/=VLOOKUP('$z'!A4,'User-Firm'!A2:B1999,2,FALSE)/g;s/Chrome.*/=VLOOKUP('$z'!A4,'User-Firm'!A2:B1999,2,FALSE)/g' LoginExcInternal.txt > Test2.txt
```

This gives me the error `sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unterminated`s' command`.

Desired Output:

```
Name1   =VLOOKUP('Mar 19'!A4,'User-Firm'!A2:B1999,2,FALSE)
Name2   =VLOOKUP('Mar 19'!A4,'User-Firm'!A2:B1999,2,FALSE)
Name3   =VLOOKUP('Mar 19'!A4,'User-Firm'!A2:B1999,2,FALSE)
```

`Mar 19` should have the apostrophes, so it should look like `'Mar 19'`

Comment: A summary of the desired output (given the sample input) would be nice for Answerers to be able to quickly compare their results; thanks!

Comment: You have a typo `z=$"(...)"` in place of `z="$(...)"` - also the space around `' $z '` will need to be removed I think

Comment: I addition to what steeldriver said, you also have other quoting issues. A single quoted string can never contain single quotes.  Please consider using https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: I made the edits along with the desired output. The single quotes show up like that which is why I posted it in this way as the final output should be in that format.

Comment: If you're using GNU `sed` or equivalent save a bunch of duplication by using one substitution with "alternation" in the pattern: `'s/(OpenFin|Chrome).*/..etc../'`. (You'll need to add sed flag `-E`  to avoid escaping parens and vert pipe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command:`sed -E "s/Chrome|OpenFin/=VLOOKUP\('Mar 19'\!A4,'User-Firm'\!A2:B1999,2,FALSE\)/g" filename|sed "s/\/[0-9]\{3\}.*//g"`

output

```
sed -E "s/Chrome|OpenFin/=VLOOKUP\('Mar 19'\!A4,'User-Firm'\!A2:B1999,2,FALSE\)/g" 
 filename|sed "s/\/[0-9]\{3\}.*//g"

Name1   =VLOOKUP('Mar 19'!A4,'User-Firm'!A2:B1999,2,FALSE)
Name2   =VLOOKUP('Mar 19'!A4,'User-Firm'!A2:B1999,2,FALSE)
Name3   =VLOOKUP('Mar 19'!A4,'User-Firm'!A2:B1999,2,FALSE
```

)

Comment: Modified a little bit to this and works like a charm, thanks!

`z="$(date -d 'last Sunday - 6 day' '+%b %y')" && sed -E "s/Chrome.*|OpenFin.*/=VLOOKUP\('$z'\!A4,'User-Firm'\!A2:B1999,2,FALSE\)/g" LoginExcInternal.txt | sed "s/\/[0-9]\{3\}.*//g" >test.txt`

Comment: Please explain this `sed "s/\/[0-9]\{3\}.*//g"` @Praveen Kumar BS

Comment: This is simplified and works: `sed -E "s/Chrome.*|OpenFin.*/=VLOOKUP\('$(date -d 'last Sunday - 6 day' '+%b %y')'\!A4,'User-Firm'\A2:B1999,2,FALSE\)/g" LoginExcInternal.txt`

Answer (score 2):

***without sed:***

```
str="=VLOOKUP('$(date -d 'last Sunday - 6 day' '+%b %y')'";
str+="$(printf "\\$(printf '%03o' '33')")";
str+="A4,'User-Firm'";
str+="$(printf "\\$(printf '%03o' '33')")";
str+="A2:B1999,2,FALSE)"; 
while read name ignored;do 
    ((${#name}))&&echo "${name}    ${str}";
done<urfile.txt
```

***with sed:***

```
sed "s/OpenFin.*$\|Chrome.*$/${str}/g" urfile.txt
```

*this should work fine*

Comment: The first one just gives me an error saying `-bash: !A4,'User: event not found` and the second only gives me the first column without adding the string I need on the second column.

Comment: you just need to escape the "!" => "\!"

Comment: Or `set +H` in the interactive `bash` session (not needed in scripts).

Comment: Escaping the ! causes the output to show the ! symbol.